# Angular project red symbol before node Module

Tags: angular, node-modules

[![I don't know why I got this red symbol before my node Module
please help me
I think because of this my bootstrap also not working][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORxrl.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORxrl.jpg)

Comment: Just check all the node modules are installed properly without any errors

Comment: Please help me ....

Comment: Delete the project and start again

Comment: i can't delete it is saying the project is already created..

Answer (score 2):

for anyone else with that problem, in Visual Studio the red icon means that the folder/file is excluded in version control. Check out common symbols here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms181372(v=vs.90)

So your bootstrap problem will have been unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Delete that node modules folder and do npm install

Comment: I did it. still i am getting same